# Excel cell to create folder which will automatically update and sync with sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365

I'm looking for ways to create folders from excel cells which will automatically update when new values are entered into a cell. I also need these folders to sync with `SharePoint`.

So far I have attempted various methods included VBA modules which don't seem to work when they should and I've used `kutools` which creates the folders but needs to be manually updated when new cells are created (also doesn't sync with SharePoint or work on any other device without kutools).

I tried this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Z = 1 To Target.Count
        If Target(Z).Value > 0 Then
            Call MakeFolders
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim maxRows As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set StartCell = Range("A1")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = 1
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To 1
        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows
            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                On Error Resume Next
            End If
        r = r + 1
        Loop
    Next c
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be detecting how many changes were made in column A and you have `Target` to tell you what they are - but you're then attempting to build folders for *every* entry in column A, *repeatedly* based on how many changes were made.

In my opinion, you'd be better off calling the `MakeFolders` routine for each change detected, but only on the cell that is being tested at the time by passing the `Target` as a parameter of `MakeFolders`.

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cellchange As Range
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cellchange In Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")).Cells
        If cellchange.Value <> "" Then
            MakeFolders ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & cellchange.Value
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub MakeFolders(folderpath As String)
    If Len(Dir(folderpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir (folderpath)
    End If
End Sub
```

You may want to add common sense checks and error trapping into the `MakeFolders` sub.

Comment: Attempted a module identical to this prior to the one I posted and started getting runtime errors, the code you have provided does not cause the same error but again doesn't succeed in creating the intended folders.

Comment: That might suggest there's a problem with the contents of the cells, rather than your code though. Have you successfully written code capable of creating a sharepoint folder?

Comment: I have done but made error of overwriting code without documenting past versions and haven't been able to get working since, attempting to use power automate as opposed to VBA as I'm struggling to make progress.

Comment: Sharepoint folders are a little trickier to create with VBA.